# Возможно ли как-то объединить мощности двух ноутбуков под Windows

Tags: windows, android-studio, администрирование, железо, ос

В данный момент времени обучаюсь программированию под андроид и столкнулся с проблемой сильного зависания android studio, при запуске эмулятора устройства (android смартфон подключить нет возможности, т.к. он отсутствует). В ноутбуке нет дискретной видеокарты, исключительно процессор intel и 4 ГБ оперативной памяти. Также нашёл ноутбук с такими же характеристиками. Возможно ли как-то объединить мощности этих двух ноутбуков через ethernet сеть к примеру и как? (оба на Windows)

Comment: Вам нужно добавить память в ваш ноутбук, как минимум ещё восемь Гб. Посмотрите в Task Manager сколько памяти занято в тот момент, когда запускаете эмулятор устройства